# How to access to configuration file from a library layer?

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have a c# project that follow domain driven design. Layers follow like this:

- API (not library and has startup, config etc.)
- Application (library)
- Domain (library)
- Infrastructure (library)

I have a data seeder in Infrastructure that will insert predefined data to database and I want to move it to config so I can update when I need easily without code deployment.  Only API layer has startup&config and it is already accessing other 3 library projects so I cant simply add API layer and use its ApplicationConfiguration. What would be best approach  to access to configuration file from a library layer in projects have multiple layers?

Note: API layer is only have endpoints and related methods. I think it won't be good idea to add a seeder in API layer.

Comment: You should have the configuration file in the API project, read the configuration there and pass the data to the Infrastructure layer.

Comment: Thanks but what about the config model? config model is only accessible from API layer. I dont have any common config models in domain, application or infrastructure layers.

Comment: What kind of configuration it is? Can you share an example?

Comment: it is appsettings.json file. I cant paste screens to comment but added to the solution that helps my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked similar projects following domain driven design and found a project model structure that helps to solve my problem: https://github.com/kgrzybek/sample-dotnet-core-cqrs-api

My models were in API layer:

[image]

I decided to move application config/setting models to application layer:
[image]